# Why is `[] == false` is true but just `[]` evaluates to true?

Tags: javascript

The following prints 'A' as expected, since the data type is different so the array is coaxed into a primitive form which is `false` for empty arrays.

```
if ([] == false)
    console.log('A');
else
    console.log('B');
```

But then why the following code too prints 'A'?

```
if ([])
    console.log('A');
else
    console.log('B');
```

Comment: JavaScript type coercion - `[] === false` is `false`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is `[] == false` is true

Because arrays behave oddly when compared to primitive values.

In particular, when you [compare](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) any non-boolean to a boolean, the boolean is handled as a number. Then, when you compare a number to an object the object is [converted to a primitive](http://es5.github.io/#x9.1) - which [stringifies](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8) the array before again comparing it to the number. Now, that string [is converted to a number](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3) so that they can be compared:

```
[] == false
[] == 0
"" == 0
0 == 0
```

Similarly, you can try

```
[1] == true
[1] == 1
"1" == 1
1 == 1
```

or

```
[2] == true
[2] == 1
"2" == 1
2 == 1
```

> but just `[]` evaluates to true?

Because [any object is truthy](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3).

Answer (score 2):

The first test returns true because of these [equality rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) :

> If one of the operands is Boolean, the Boolean operand is converted to
>   1 if it is true and +0 if it is false.
>
> If an object is compared with a number or string, JavaScript attempts
>   to return the default value for the object. Operators attempt to
>   convert the object to a primitive value, a String or Number value,
>   using the valueOf and toString methods of the objects. If this attempt
>   to convert the object fails, a runtime error is generated.

(and yes, you do have `[].toString()==""` and thus `[]==0`)

The second test

```
if ([])
```

simply is passed because all objects are truish.

Answer (score 2):

The `==` operator forces a type cast. `[]` as boolean is `false`. Why doesn't the same happen with eg. `"a" == false`? Basically, the numeric value of `[]` is `0`, while the numeric value of `"a"` is `NaN`. Predictably, `"0" == false` is `true` :)

On the other hand, in the second case, you're basically just checking if `[]` exists ("isn't null"). There is no casting to boolean.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is an empty array and different than `false` that is why `[] == false` returns `false` WHILE `[]` returns `true` because it is not pointing on a `null`