# If both [0] == 0 and 0 == [[0]] are true than why is [0] == [[0]] false?

Tags: javascript

We all know javascript does funky conversions when testing for equality, but what exactly happens under the hood?

```
> [0] == 0
true
> 0 == [[0]]
true
> [0] == [[0]]
false
```

Yes, it was naive of me to expect transitivity from == operator.

Comment: "Yes, it was naive of me to expect transitivity from == operator." - indeed. There are plenty of examples

Comment: Just a side note, read this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/why-is-10 This helped me a lot to understand why such conditions are either true, false, 1, 0 or whatever.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22231191/1048572

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[0] == 0` and `0 == [[0]]` compares a primitive value with an object and thus **type conversion** will be performed. In both cases `[0]` and `[[0]]` will eventually be converted to the primitive value `0`.

This is defined in steps 8 (and 9) of the [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3):

> 8. If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object,
>      return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).

However, `[0] === [[0]]` compares two objects and two different objects are never equal to each other:

> 1f. Return true if *x* and *y* refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.

---

Here is a slightly simper example that demonstrates that loose comparison is not transitive:

```
" " == 0 // true
"\n" == 0 // true
" " == "\n" // false
```

The first two comparisons perform type conversion (string to number), the last one does not and the values of both strings are different.

Answer (score 2):

Your first 2 examples implicitly converts the arrays to strings, then compares those to the `0`:

```
var a = [0].toString(); // "0"
var b = a == 0 // "0" == 0; // true
```

The last example doesn't cast the arrays, it just compares the arrays' identities.
These don't match, obviously, so `false` is returned.

The extra layer of depth you have in some of those arrays doesn't make a difference, in your examples:

```
[0] == [0]     // false, they're not the same array.
0 == [[[[0]]]] // true, [[[[0]]]].toString() === "0", "0" == 0
```

---

As [@JanDvorak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499214/jan-dvorak) mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703580/if-both-0-0-and-0-0-are-true-than-why-is-0-0-false#comment43819536_27703742) on [@KooiInc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58186/kooiinc)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27703742/1835379), behind the scenes, JS doesn't use `toString` for this conversion. However, in concept this is what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is as per JavaScript [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)

1. Comparing **[0] == 0** - Operand types are different

> **Matches Case 9 of algo**: Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String
>   or Number
>   **result**: [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1)(x) == y. i.e '0' == 0, hence *true*

2. Comparing **0 == [[0]]** - Operand types are different

> **Matches Case 8 of algo**: If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object,
>      **result**: x == ToPrimitive(y). i.e 0 == '0', hence *true*

3. Comparing [0] == [[0]] - Operand types are same i.e object

> **Matches Case 1 of algo**: Type(x) is the same as Type(y),
>       if type is 'object' Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.
>       i.e reference will be matched, hence false