# For an array (array == 0) is true and for a non-empty array (array == 0) is false why?

Tags: javascript

```
let x = [];
if(x==0) 
    console.log('Hello')
```

The about code prints 'Hello'

```
let x = [ 1 ];
if(x==0) 
    console.log('Hello');
```

The above code does not print 'Hello'.

Why?

Comment: Many related questions that contain the answer. See [Why does {} == false evaluate to false while \[\] == false evaluates to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27989285/218196) and [If both \[0\] == 0 and 0 == \[\[0\]\] are true than why is \[0\] == \[\[0\]\] false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27703580/218196). `[] == 0` and `[] == false` are the same because `false` is converted to `0`.

Comment: @DenIsahac: How is that a duplicate?

Comment: [] is falsy, 0 is falsy. Falsy == Falsy === true. Pretty simple mate.

Comment: @Mardoxx: Except that `[]` is not falsey. It's not *that* straightforward. Have a look at the links I posted in my first comment.

Comment: @Mardoxx When objects of different types are compared, one of them is converted to the other type. It doesn't just compare their truthiness.

Comment: @Mardoxx For example `true == 3` is false, even though both are truthy. `true` is converted to a number, so it's equivalent to `1 === 3`.

Answer (score 1):

While I think this should be closed as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989285/why-does-false-evaluate-to-false-while-false-evaluates-to-true), before any more false statements are made:

`==` performs type conversion. This is the type conversion that takes place according to the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3):

```
[] == 0                    // step 9 ToPrimitve([]) == 0
"" == 0                    // step 5 ToNumber("") == 0
0 == 0                     // step 1.c.iii

[1] == 0                   // step 9 ToPrimitve([1]) == 0
"1" == 0                   // step 5 ToNumber("1") == 0
1 == 0                     // step 1.c.iii
```

References: [ToNumber](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3), [ToPrimitive](http://es5.github.io/#x9.1)